# Python split() method not working properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

I want to use split() method for separating rupees and paise. In paise part it is showing 6 paise for 60 paise, 7 for 70 and so on.But if the paise is 44 it will show correctly.Is it not considering zero if it is at the end?
[rupees and paise are Indian currency]

```
from num2words import num2words

pre=405068.60
text1 = ''
text2 = ''
result1 = ''
result2 = ''
entire_num = int((str(pre).split('.'))[0])
decimal_num = int((str(pre).split('.'))[1])
print "Decimal number=%d" %decimal_num
text1=num2words(entire_num, lang='en_IN').capitalize()
text2=num2words(decimal_num, lang='en_IN')
result1=text1+' '+'rupees'
if(decimal_num>0):
    result2 = ' and '+text2+' paise'
print result1+result2
```

Comment: Despite the fact you specify your value `pre` as `405068.60` it will convert to string as `405068.6`. it does not preserve the trailing 0's.

Comment: Instead of using `str(pre)` use `str.format('{:.2f}', pre)`, `str(100.20)` equals `"100.2"`, whereas `str.format('{:.2f}', pre)` equals `"100.20"`

Comment: Initialize `pre` as a string: `pre='405068.60'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to explicitly format the string you convert `pre` into, e.g.:

```
>>> str.format('{:.2f}', pre)
'405068.60'
```

Whereas:

```
>>> str(pre)
'405068.6'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because

```
pre=405068.60
```

is the same as

```
pre=405068.6
```

Python will remove trailing 0's from floats. You can test this easily:

```
>>> pre=405068.60
>>> print pre
405068.6
```

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code a little and wrapped it in a function.

The important thing when working with currency is to store the numbers as strings so that trailing zeroes aren't lost and that you don't get problems due to the way floating-point rounding works.

I've modified your logic slightly so that the code can handle rupees given with or without a decimal point, and it can handle amounts of paise with no digits before the decimal point.

```
from num2words import num2words

def format_currency(amount):
    if '.' not in amount:
        amount += '.'

    rupees, paise = amount.split('.')

    if rupees:
        rupees = num2words(int(rupees), lang='en_IN').capitalize() + ' rupees'
    if paise:
        paise = num2words(int(paise), lang='en_IN') + ' paise'
        if rupees:
            paise = ' and ' + paise
    return rupees + paise

data = ('405068.60', '12345.', '678', '321.75', '.25')

for u in data:
    print '{0} -> {1}'.format(u, format_currency(u))
```

**output**

```
405068.60 -> Four lakh, five thousand and sixty-eight rupees and sixty paise
12345. -> Twelve thousand, three hundred and forty-five rupees
678 -> Six hundred and seventy-eight rupees
321.75 -> Three hundred and twenty-one rupees and seventy-five paise
.25 -> twenty-five paise
```

You may wish to change the last `if` statement in the function to

```
    if rupees:
        paise = ' and ' + paise
    else:
        paise = paise.capitalize()
```

which will cause plain paise amounts to be capitalised.

Also, you can use the `.title` method instead of `capitalize` to achieve this sort of output:

```
405068.60 -> Four Lakh, Five Thousand And Sixty-Eight rupees and sixty paise
12345. -> Twelve Thousand, Three Hundred And Forty-Five rupees
678 -> Six Hundred And Seventy-Eight rupees
321.75 -> Three Hundred And Twenty-One rupees and seventy-five paise
.25 -> Twenty-Five Paise
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply